# phpmyadmin on Xampp gives suddenly 403

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I have been using Xampp for years but suddenly I cannot access phpmyadmin anymore.

I get

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Mijn xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php:

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';



/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

And the relevant part of my httpd-xampp.conf:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
    

    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Directory>

   
</IfModule>
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it is configured allow only from localhost (same computer on wich is running xampp), so if you are trying from a lan client you should add a line to the alis config like this `Require ip 192.168.1.0/24` (edit accordingly to lan network).

Plus it is saying that while trying to fecth the error page it encountered a 403 error (permission denied). So it's possible that showing the 403 it's not the real error but the last one.

You should look at the apache log to verify the first error

Comment: I checked the log and it suggested there was an ssl error. I can open it with https. I experimented with ssl and xampp in the past and I think this is the result ;-) Strangely the xampp dashboard opens with http.

Comment: In the alias config there is this line: "SSLRequireSSL", if you don't want ssl remove it

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf
```

Then go to Directory tag as below:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
```

and then in the Directory tag change as below:

From

```
Require local
```

To

```
Require all granted
```

`Restart the Xampp`

That's it!